# 18 plates with 6 distinct objects

Tags: combinatorics

6 distinct objects are to be arranged on 18 plates, each plate can hold a maximum of 1 object, with at least 2 empty plates between every object. How many ways can they be arranged?

**My Attempt:**

1xx2xx3xx4xx5xx6

Where x, represents empty plates.
**these objects can be arranged in 6! ways.**

There are a **remaining of 2 more empty plates to be inserted** to complete the arrangement.

_1_2_3_4_5_6_

a+b+c+d+e+f+g = 2  (bars and stars method)

**Hence the remaining 2 plates could be arranged 8c2 ways**

**Final ans: 8c2 * 6!**

**Correct ans: 12c4 *6!**

Comment: are plates also distict?

Comment: Your ans is correct !